# Is it possible to make parent class Generic in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I have a situation where I have multiple DAO classes which I use to fetch result from hibernate queries, I want to add count as an additional column in each DAO for record count and looking for a solution from generics. something like.

```
class GenericResult extends <DAO as generic parameter> {
Long count;
}
```

So that I can replace the DAO and reuse the GenricResult anywhere I want.

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(qlString, SpecificDao.class)
```

I want to replace above line with

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(qlString, GenricResult.class)
```

Comment: No. <padding...>

Comment: @AndyTurner, any alternate way you think to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you think it would be useful to *extend* particular DAO classes?

Comment: close you can do is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563979/repository-design-pattern-should-there-be-one-repo-for-every-dao/44581300#44581300

Comment: I want to return a count along with the result for filter queries. So when where clause returns 2 records I want to return 2 as count along with records, 
I thought having a reusable generic class is better idea so I will not have to modify much of my code otherwise now I have to create each GnericResult class for each DAO

Comment: in that case you can design your common class which will hold count and all you have to do is add `list.size()` to that variable

Comment: issue is I am using pagination and my result is filtered in below way.
query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(qlString, SpeficDTO.class) .setFirstResult((page.intValue() - 1) * limit.intValue()).setMaxResults(limit.intValue());

return query.getResultList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics simply provides a way to omit explicit casts.

If you can't do something with casting, you can't do it with generics either.

You can't do this with casting, so you can't do it with generics.

---

I would question whether inheritance is really what you want here. An alternative would be composition:

```
class GenericResult<D> {
  Long count;

  D getDao();
}
```

which provides access to a DAO, but a `GenericResult` is-not-a DAO, which seems more correct to me.